# python httplib: connect through proxy with authentification

Tags: python, proxy, httplib

I am trying to send GET request through a proxy with authentification.
I have the following existing code:

```
import httplib

username = 'myname'
password = '1234'
proxyserver = "136.137.138.139"
url       = "http://google.com"
c         = httplib.HTTPConnection(proxyserver, 83, timeout = 30)
c.connect()  
c.request("GET", url)
resp = c.getresponse()
data = resp.read()
print data
```

when running this code, I get an answer from the proxy saying that I must provide authentification, which is correct.
In my code, I don't use login and password. My problem is that i don't know how to use  them !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this code if you specifically want to use `httplib`.
https://gist.github.com/beugley/13dd4cba88a19169bcb0

But you could also use the easier `requests` module.

```
import requests
proxies = {
    "http": "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/",
    # "https": "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/",
}
url = 'http://google.com'
data = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.I have tried with the requests module, and it works well. But I would like to use only built-in modules. I have also tried the example given in "gist.github". It works also well. But If I change port from 443 to 80, then I get an error: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590). What's wrong with standard http request on port 80? Note: it works well with the requests module with a url like 'http://...."

Comment: 80 is the standard port for http. But for https, it is 443.

Comment: Does it mean that the code provided in [https://gist.github.com/beugley/13dd4cba88a19169bcb0] works only for https request, meaning that you cannot change the port to 80?

Comment: Did you try httplib.HTTPConnection instead of httplib.HTTPSConnection?

Comment: yes, I just tried it 1 hour ago, and it works. Thanks you very much for your answers.